# Wordpress: single.php shows the newest post only

Tags: wordpress, loops, themes

I'm developing a wordpress 3.3.1 theme and I'm having troubles with the single.php file.
It displays - no matter what post (&p=111 e.g.) you select - only the content of the newest post.

This is my loop:

```
            <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
            <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>


            <h1 class="page-title"><?php the_title() ?></h1>

            <?php if (has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ): ?>
            <?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail' ); ?>
            <img src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>" class="cover" />
            <?php endif; ?>

            <p class="page-text">
                <?php the_content(); ?>     
            </p>

            <?php endwhile; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
```

What could be wrong? I hope you've understood my problem. Thank you!

edit:

I recently updated the header file. When I delete this loop, it works fine:

```
                        <ul class="nav-dropdown">
                        <?php
                            $cat_args = array(
                              'orderby' => 'name',
                              'order' => 'ASC',
                              'child_of' => 5,
                              'exclude' => '1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9,10,11,12,13,14'
                            );
                            $categories = get_categories($cat_args); 
                            foreach($categories as $category) {

                                 $post_args = array(
                                  'category' => $category->term_id
                                );
                                $posts = get_posts($post_args);

                                foreach($posts as $post) {
                        ?>
                            <li class="nav-dropdown"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="pagelink"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
                        <?php
                                }
                            }
                        ?>
                        </ul>
```

Comment: Have you tried echoing $post->ID? And if so, does it match the requested post?

Comment: @TomWalters Yes, I've tried that. It does not match the requested post.

Comment: Well playing around with such variables in the header is bound to mess up your theme! Whack a wp_reset_query(); at the end of your header and see if that fixes it.

Comment: Sadly, it doesnt fix it. I've tried wp_reset_query() and wp_reset_postdata(). Shall I rename the variables?

Comment: Yeah that might do it, as long as you don't have anything else in your header that works on $post variables.

Comment: Great, it worked! Thanks for working that out with me. You can add an answer if you'd like to and i'll set is as "accepted".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd change your variable names in the header as ones such as `$post` are reserved by Wordpress for handling single post pages.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure but please change the `$post` variable to any other variable and than try
may be your problem be solved.

Because `$post` is global variable of post.